# How to return the members of an AD group using ActiveDirectory 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, active-directory

I'm using ActiveDirectory2 to query LDAP, but, I've been trying to return the users of a group without any luck.

The usage is like this:

```
ad.authenticate(config.USERNAME, config.PASSWORD, function(err, auth) {

  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  if (auth) {
    console.log('Authenticated!');
    let groupName = 'POL-Application-CustomerCenter-POL-PAC-Supervisor';
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          ad.getUsersForGroup(groupName, function(err, users) {
              if (err) {
                  console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
                  reject(err.message);
                  return;
              }

              if (! users) {
                console.log('Group: ' + groupName + ' not found.');

              }
              else {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
                  resolve(users);
                  return users;
              }
          });
        });
  console.log('promise',JSON.stringify(promise))
}
  else {
    console.log('Authentication failed!');
  }
});
```

And this promise I'm trying to get out of that callback is always empty; I know this should be done some other way, so, any ideas would be highly appreciated, I'm getting a headache and the library site does not give any other examples than those.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "that callback is always empty", do you mean that `JSON.stringify(promise)` is always `{}`? That will serialize the properties of the actual `Promise` object into JSON, not *the result* of the operation.

I think you want to `await` the promise. Using `await` will:

1. Asynchronously wait until the `Promise` completes
2. Return the value that the `Promise` passed to the `resolve()` method

So I think you want this:

```
console.log('promise',JSON.stringify(await promise));
```

You can read about the `await` operator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: My mistake. That promise wrapper is my code, the original code simply has a callback, and inside this callback the author's example serialises the users. 

`var groupName = 'Employees'; var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config); ad.getUsersForGroup(groupName, function(err, users) { if (err) { console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err)); return; } if (! users) console.log('Group: ' + groupName + ' not found.'); else { console.log(JSON.stringify(users)); } }); `

I need those users out, so I wrote that promise wrapper. I'll try awaiting.

Comment: Right. So even in your code, you should be seeing something in the console from this line: `console.log(JSON.stringify(users));` Are you?

Comment: I do, I see those users.

Comment: Awesome. So yes, I think you're just missing `await` and everything should work for you.